# NSDateComponents vs timeIntervalSince

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I am trying to calculate the number of days from one date to another and have found two ways of doing so.

The first uses NSDateComponents as follows:

```
NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                                    fromDate:date1
                                                      toDate:date2
                                                     options:0];
```

and then checking the [components day].

The second uses timeInterval:

```
    NSInteger timeInterval = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
```

and then getting timeInterval/3600/24

Is one way better than the other (perhaps because of lack precision with the timeInterval methods)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using dateComponent is far more better then manipulation yourself by assuming `timeInterval/3600/24`.

Reason:

1. All days doesn't have 60*60*24 seconds!!!
2. While transition from daylight  saving time where one day can have 23 or 25 hours.

> The hour (common symbol: h or hr) is a unit of measurement of time. In
>   modern usage, an hour comprises 60 minutes, or 3,600 seconds. It is
>   approximately 1/24 of a mean solar day.
>
> An hour in the Universal Coordinated Time (UTC) time standard can
>   include a negative or positive leap second, and may therefore have a
>   duration of 3,599 or 3,601 seconds for adjustment purposes.

Source:[Wikipedia Hour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hour).

Comment: Leap seconds are *not* the reason that you should use NSDateComponents, because the Unix time does not count leap seconds. The Unix time number increases exactly by 3600 every hour. - The real reason is the transition from and to Daylight Saving Time, where one day may have 23 or 25 hours.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! Right on regarding DST.